# How is a mediator pattern ( in GOF ) different from container / presentational components in reactjs (intent)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns, ui-patterns

it looks like they are the same, In mediator we have to explicitly call in other colleagues that some thing has changed, while in presentational / container components the container is re-rendered (may due to some state change) which might be due to an observer pattern. How a mediator and container / presentational components differ in intent is what I am not sure of.

Comment: What do you mean by "*call in other colleagues*"?

Comment: Yes, react (the library) could be considered to be a mediator between the individual components. However I'm not sure what exactly you are asking. A pattern is not the same as a component.

Comment: @Bergi by colleagues I mean the objects / components in the mediator - I think it is the container component which can be referred  to as the Mediator in this case.

Comment: Can you share some simple code example of what you mean by "container component"? And in React you rarely (if ever) hold a reference to a component instance, so it's not clear how you think that one can be a mediator object.